# Authorize a random Facebook Page to my Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to user Facebook's app webhook to read all incomming-messages of all Facebook Pages which authorized my Facebook's app to do that.

I also want to use my backend service to send reply back to senders on behafl of received-facebook-page.

I have facebook account named **fbaccount1**. **fbaccount1** have a Facebook App named **fbapp1** and its in development mode. **fbaccount1** also have a Page, named **fbpage1**.

I have a webhook service in my site. After some setting in Facebook Developer Console, my webhook service can receive any messages sent to **fbpage1** from a test user.

I implemented login with Facebook into my site. Any random user choose to login with Facebook, a dialog will show and ask: **fbapp1** want you authorized it to access your info...

Questions:

- Facebook does not allow me to ask *manage_pages* permisson from other user if my **fbapp1** is in dev mode. Is there other way to do it?
- is it possible for this flow:

  - **fbaccount2** authorized **fbapp1** with *manage_pages* permission
  - **fbapp1** can get all **fbaccount2**'s page id and acess token (**fbpage2**)
  - my site's backend can subscribe **fbpage2** to **fbapp1**
  - **fbapp1** can read all messages sent to **fbpage2** and send them to my webhook

URL to subscribe a page to my FB app (webhook is enabled for the app):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/{page_id}/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=pages_messaging
```

Comment: Why not just get your app approved? Dev mode is for testing.

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review/ and 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review/

Comment: thank @WizKid but im in developing phase, and dont have enough info to sumbit a review yet :(

Comment: oh, maybe I should try to submit a review for invidual. thank you WizKid and Iars,schwarz

Comment: Why would you need more accounts and pages for the testing? Just use fbaccount1 and fbapp1 and fbpage1.

Comment: All you need to do is add fbaccount2 to a role in your app.

Comment: @WizKid yeah, i tested like that already, and its succed. But im worring that when i publish my FB app, will my webhook service be able to capture messages of any random Page authozied my FB app to do that? Or my webhook service be able to capture messages of my account's page only.

Comment: @misorude thank you. i added fbaccount2 to dev/test role to my app. But I cant select fbpage2 to subscribe. its not in page list when I log to app dashboard as fbaccount1.

when i added fbaccount2 as an admin to the app, i can log to App dashboard as fbaccount2 then select fbpage2 to subscribe to my webhook, and its worked.